# VS2010: Checkboxes have gray background on the white Tab in dialog. How to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, user-interface

I am adding a new dialog to the C++ application (Visual Studio 2010). I cannot get rid of the gray background of checkboxes that are placed on the tab that is white by default:

[image: Dialog being edited in the resource editor]

The related text in the .rc file is the following:

```
IDD_ExportHTML DIALOGEX 164, 128, 292, 136
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif", 0, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "statFileName0",102,9,9,59,8
    LTEXT           "statFileName",101,9,20,190,8
    CONTROL         "",150,"SysTabControl32",TCS_RAGGEDRIGHT,11,38,201,92
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "btnOK",IDOK,241,97,45,15
    PUSHBUTTON      "btnCancel",IDCANCEL,241,115,45,15
    CONTROL         "chboxLines",106,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,34,71,135,12
    CONTROL         "chboxBackground",107,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,34,84,135,12
    CONTROL         "chboxPaging",108,"Button",BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_TABSTOP,34,98,135,12
END
```

It behaves the same way when the application runs. What should I set or do tell the checkboxes they are children of the tab? Or how can I fix the problem

Thanks for your time and experience,
   Petr

Comment: Have you tried setting the Transparency of each checkbox to true in VS?

Comment: @newenglander: Yes I did. But it does not make a difference. It seems as if it takes the dialog gray window as the parent of the checkboxes, and not the tab window as a parent.

Comment: can't you change the checkbox background color to white? .Net Winform controls aren't trasparent... the best they can do is assume the same background color of their parent control

Comment: @Max: This is a native C++ application and the native Windows controls used via resources (no .Net Winforms). The native checkbox control window should have the tab as the parent window and the default action of the WM_CTLCOLORBTN sent to the parent should be to erase the background using the parent background (could also be a bitmap, gradient shading, etc. -- so solid color should not be set as a child background).

Comment: @pepr opps... sorry, I didn't read your question carefully (the 99% question highlighted in my StackOverflow account are .Net related :-))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
HBRUSH CYourDialogHere::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{

    HBRUSH hbr = (HBRUSH)m_brush;
    CWnd *pCheckBox = GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1);  // put ID of your checkbox here.

    if (*pCheckBox == *pWnd)
    {
        pDC->SetBkColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    }
    else
        hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    return hbr;
}
```

More info is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117778)

I don't know how much is your C++ skills, but you have to also add some lines in .h file of your project to include this OnCtlColor function and some change in message map of your dialog .cpp file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Actually, I am using ATL/WTL, but there are similar ways to handle WM_CTLCOLORxxx. I also wanted to make sure that it must be done explicitly.